# An exception occurred while completing a multipart upload: Error executing "CompleteMultipartUpload"

Tags: xml, exception, aws, upload, http-request

I am writing this since I have literally no idea in how to debug this anymore. I have a custom module that creates a csv feed and the uploads it to a digital ocean remote storage (space or whatever it's name is).

The problem is that the feed generates correctly but whenever it tries to upload to DigitalOcean, it throws the following error:

```
An exception occurred while completing a multipart upload: Error executing "CompleteMultipartUpload" on 
<here I have the link to my space> 

AWS HTTP error: Client error: POST <here I have the link to my digital ocean space>;
resulted in a 400 Bad Request response:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
<Code>MalformedXML</Code>
<BucketName>
<space_name_for_prod>
</BucketName>
<RequestId> (truncated...)
MalformedXML (client):  - 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
<Code>MalformedXML</Code>
<BucketName>
<space_name_for_production>
</BucketName>
<RequestId>
<some_request_id>
</RequestId>
<HostId>
<some_host_id></HostId>
</Error>
```

I tested with the clasic file storage on local and it works flawlessly but whenever I'm switching to remote storage it gives me this error. I tried finding the request that goes to DigitalOcean but I'm spinning my head around those requests from aws-sdk-php module/extensions.

I am out of ideas :(